# Copy only difference (new) files with gcloud compute copy-files

Tags: linux, debian, google-compute-engine, rsync, gcloud

is it possible to copy ONLY changed/updated files from my DEBIAN Server to Google Cloud Instance, instead of copying ALL files all the time? I want to backup my machine 4 times a day.

I am using "gcloud compute copy-files"

Thnks,
Florian

Comment: Voting to close this question as off-topic. Please note that Stackoverflow is for programming related questions only. Please review the [help/on-topic] for what topics can be asked here. The help also has suggestions for other SE sites where this question may be appropriate.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 7):

`gcloud compute copy-files` is backed by SCP, which has no support for incremental file uploads.

That said, you can use any tool that uses the SSH protocol (like [`rsync`](https://kyup.com/tutorials/copy-files-rsync-ssh/)) to get incremental uploads. `gcloud compute copy-files --dry-run` will show you the SSH options used:

```
$ gcloud compute copy-files --dry-run --zone asia-east1-c /tmp/test.data zjn-nix:
/usr/local/bin/scp -i /Users/zjn/.ssh/google_compute_engine -o UserKnownHostsFile=/Users/zjn/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o CheckHostIP=no -o HostKeyAlias=compute.17446274288301719340 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=yes -r /tmp/test.data zjn@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:
```

You'll have to plug similar options into rsync, or put them in your `~/.ssh/config` file.